# How to get volume name from Iscsi target?

Tags: powershell, iscsi

I am trying to get volume name from Iscsi target. But i can get only nodeaddress.

```
Get-IscsiTarget | select NodeAddress
```

NodeAddress is having volume name plus some unique identification strings.

Is it possible to get the volume name alone from IScsi target?

Comment: Use `Get-Member` on it and find out?  According to [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826102(v=wps.630).aspx), it returns a CIM-wrapped object

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but you might be able to just do this:

```
Get-IscsiTarget | Get-iSCSISession | Get-Disk -iSCSISession | Get-Partition | Get-Volume
```

Otherwise, [the iSCSI documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826102%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) suggests something like this might get you a `MSFT_Disk` from the `MSFT_iSCSITarget` that `Get-IscsiTarget` returns, and [the Storage Management documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830525(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests you can get to volumes from that.

```
Get-IscsiTarget | 
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association MSFT_iSCSITargetToiSCSISession -Namespace 'root\microsoft\windows\storage' -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association MSFT_iSCSISessionToDisk  -Namespace 'root\microsoft\windows\storage' -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association MSFT_DiskToPartition -Namespace 'root\microsoft\windows\storage' -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association MSFT_PartitionToVolume -Namespace 'root\microsoft\windows\storage'
```

That should return the `MSFT_Volume`.  I'm not 100% sure about the namespaces above.